# Concatenate columns SQL Server function

Tags: sql-server

I have a dataset with columns like: Cause_1, Cause_2, Cause_3...Solution_1,Solution_2,Solution_3 and so on. I've been asked to concatenate these columns into 2...Cause and Solution.

I'd like to create a SQL Server function to be able to concatenate each group of columns into one. Each value should be separated by semicolon.

Please note that these are not the only columns that I'd need to concatenate that way, so that's the reason that I think a function is the most appropriate solution.

Comment: So you want a single function that would take a variable number of columns? Cant have variable number of parameters to a function so that's out. Any reason you wouldn't just concatenate them using string concatenation? I can think of various ways to do it with use of information_schema and dynamic sql but none that would not be horribly inefficient.

Comment: Thanks Tom. Well, I tried, but I found several groups of columns like these in my dataset. So, I thought, it might be simpler to think in something like that if possible. Thanks!

Comment: By the way, I found CONCAT_WS() in SQL 2017. That sounds like a simple one to implement. But, I'm still at SQL 2016. So, I'm getting error 'CONCAT_WS' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: What are the datatype of these columns, causes and solutions? Are they all varchar?

Comment: Yes they are all varchar @Dimith

Answer (score 1):

Are the columns all being stored as varchars or any other text based datatype?
Is so you can join the strings with a simple '+'
For example

```
Select Cause_1 + ' ' + Solution_1 AS Cause_and_Solution1
FROM your_data
```

The concept could also be copied into a function for reuse if you wish

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think I didn't make myself clear. I'll try to explain a bit better. I have several columns(not a fix number of columns) storing the same concept (e.g. Cause). What I'm trying to do is to create a function that can concatenate all columns referring to the same concept into one.

Comment: Hi Hans,
I can think of some options, but first,could I get a little ore information please
"I have several columns(not a fix number of columns)"

The number of columns must be fixed for a single table.
Do you mean that this is to be used over several tables, all with different column definitions? or that in the one table some of the columns will be blank?

Comment: Thanks @freshAir the table might be a parameter as well. But, in my case all columns are varchar. I found this solution. However it's still implies hardcode: <!-- language: lang-js -->STUFF( COALESCE('; ' + [causeTechnical - 1], '') + 
    COALESCE('; ' + [causeTechnical - 2], '') + 
    COALESCE('; ' + [causeTechnical - 3], '') + 
    COALESCE('; ' + [causeTechnical - 4], '') + 
    COALESCE('; ' + [causeTechnicalOther], ''),1, 2, '') AS CauseTechnical

Comment: So the function will receive a table name as a parameter? and all tables will have a different column setup?

Do you have much experience using dynamic SQL? If you don't wish to hardcode I believe dynamic would be your only option. Without more details I cant provide much more guidance than that, except that this could get complicated. If there is only a small number of tables (and they are unlikely to change anytime soon) you might be better off with static SQL on each table
Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your help @freshAir. I'll have a look at dynamic SQL. In this case all columns are varchar and are into one particular table.

Comment: That's what I was suggesting earlier. You can find all the column names from information_schema.columns that match your prefix, then build up dynamic sql that re-reads the row from the table, then concatenates all the columns into one. But dont even think about it! Performance will suck. Just do the hard work and do a simple `cause_1+isnull(';'+cause_2)+isnull(;+cause_3) etc. Dont know why you need the STUFF function.

Comment: Seconding @TomC's comments.
Dynamic SQL can be very powerful, but also can cause problems when not cafeful